# Prestashop ajax registration bug

Tags: ajax, prestashop

I'm trying to run prestashop. I had already made custom theme and I have problem with registration. When somebody tries to register during checkout he receives an error:

TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to load form. Details: Error thrown: [object Object] Text status: error

I can't figure out where to search for solution. Or maybe someone know how to disable ajax registration?

Regards.

Comment: Look at the button's Id you're using to submit the form. All the ajax functions are triggered from order-opc.js or order-address.js. With this you will be able to see where the error is coming from. Without more informations we can't help you

Comment: I'm modifying standard theme and submit button id is "SubmitCreate". But I cannot find reference to it in order-opc.js nor in order-address.js

Any other ideas?

Comment: What version of Prestashop are you using?

Comment: Im using version 1.5.2 and I had found a solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had found a solution. Most of sources told that i should turn off mobile functionality in theme. I did so, but it didn't help. So I checked form it was referencing to certain adress but AJAX request was directed to homepage.

So I'd modified AJAX request in file so it directs same place as form.

In /themes/default/authentication.tpl about line 97 there was line:

```
url: baseUri,
```

I had changed it to:

```
url: baseUri + 'index.php?controller=authentication',
```

so AJAX request goes under right address. After that I had to change some mobile authentication forms under /themes/default/mobile/authentication*.tpl , so they contains a field to enter telephone number. Everything that solved whole problem.

Comment: Also, if one has that error AND is making a custom theme, he should check the authentication.tpl file for javascript references to #center_column, and change theme accordingly if necessary

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

> In admin panel go to, Advanced paramaters>performance, scroll down to
>   CCC (Combine, Compress and Cache), and choose Keep inline JavaScript
>   in HTML as original.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of errors like

```
TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to load form. Details: Error thrown: [object Object] Text status: error
```

in One Page Checkout (OPC)

are related with unhooked **blockuserinfo** (or changed hook of this module) from the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Another source for this problem can be blockcart/ajax-cart.js

In some situations it triggers ajaxCart.refresh() on domready even if not needed (in fact: in every f*n' page), and so sometimes it gets back an html (the home) document instead of an ajax one, thus generating the tech error we're speaking of.

To solve, I just overridden blockcart/ajax-cart.js and simply commented out the alert in case of error on ajaxCart.refresh(). 
It's not an elegant solution but, honestly, since that is caused by some really bad js architecture (read: a bug somewhere), and since I don't think that alert is useful to any frontend user, I also think it doesn't hurt to comment it out.

The Prestashop team has never been particularly smart on writing javascript, so I often end up rewriting from scratch. But in this case I think that small override it's better.